# Some questions on stereochemistry

Tags: stereochemistry

I have a couple of basic questions on stereochemistry that confused me. Please help me understand them.

1) Why does a molecule become achiral if it has a plane of symmetry even though it has steriocentes?

2) When working with Fischer Projections, they say you can rotate a Fischer projection 180 degrees, but not by 90 degrees. I don't understand why.

Moreover, can you please suggest me a good resource wherein I can learn stereochemistry (not to very advanced level)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Why does a molecule become achiral if it has a plane of symmetry
>   even though it has stereocenters?

If a plane of symmetry bisects a molecule such that one half of the bisected molecule is the mirror image of the other half of the bisected molecule, then the entire molecule *must* be superimposable on its mirror image, it must be achiral.  Said differently, if mirror symmetry exists within a molecule, then the mirror image of the entire molecule will be superimposable upon the original drawing of the entire molecule.

Here's an example of a molecule ($\ce{A}$) with 2 chiral groups ($\ce{G_{R}}$ and ($\ce{G_{S}}$).  There is a plane of symmetry that bisects $\ce{A}$, it is perpendicular to the plane of the screen and contains the central carbon atom and the 2 methyl groups.  Now, when we draw the mirror image of $\ce{A}$ (let's call it ($\ce{\bar{A}}$), we find that it is superimposable upon the original drawing of $\ce{A}$ by a simple 180-degree rotation.
Even though $\ce{A}$ contains 2 chiral substituents, the molecule as a whole is achiral.

[image: Illustration depicting a molecule, A, as superimposable on its mirror image]

Answer (score 2):

If you rotate the substituents on a Fischer projection by 90 degrees you change the stereochemistry of each substituent.

The up/down positions on a Fischer projection indicate substituents projected **away** from you. The left and right positions indicate substituents projected **toward** you.

Here's a rotated tetrahedral molecule to help you see what I mean by the substituents are projected away/toward you.

[image]

We can represent toward using a solid wedge and away using a hatched wedge:

[image]